# Hankaku to Zenkaku and vice versa in Java

Tags: java

Is there any utility available in Java for converting between Hankaku characters and Zenkaku characters i.e. Japanese Half Width kana and Full Width kana? Or is there an algorithm or approach available that could be implemented for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/download) library has them.

```
Transliterator tr = Transliterator.getInstance("Halfwidth-Fullwidth");
String converted = tr.transliterate("ｱｲｳｴｵ");
```